# Amazon S3 allow specific domain to access bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to allow a specific domain to access my Amazon S3 bucket but after that all the domains has been dropped from Amazon S3. The url I wish to access is [https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/{bucketUri}/1.jpg](https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/%7BbucketUri%7D/1.jpg) but returns 403 forbidden on my allowed referer. I can see the Referer on the page is correct.
Here's my settings:
Block public access all off.
Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Restrict based on HTTP referrer policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucketUri}",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://reference.domain.put.here"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please note that `Referer` is not a secure way of protecting content. It can easily be faked and should be used to protect confidential information.

Comment: "*" action would include things like DeleteBucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Allow` type policies as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4), not `Deny`. Also your `Resource` is incorrect:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://reference.domain.put.here"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And please note that `aws:Referer` **does not really protect you**. It is a merely inconvenience to bypass, as you can easly spoof `aws:Referer`.

Comment: Thanks, what about other referer? I just put an Allow effect on the policy but doesn't have any deny action. Does it allow other referer?

Comment: @BillTian No it does not. But as I wrote, referrer does not prefect you from anything. Its fully explain in the link I gave in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do an explicit Allow, not Deny.  Change the referer to StringLike instead.

Comment: This is a start, but I think there is more wrong with OPs policy.

Comment: Thanks, what about other referer? I just put an Allow effect on the policy but doesn't have any deny action. Does it allow other referer?

Comment: No it will not allow other referers